# Adding new user and group

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I am trying to add a new user and group on my ubuntu machine but facing some issues with it.

First I have added a group with name `mytest` using command:

```
groupadd mytest
```

Then I am trying to add a user with same name using command:

```
useradd mytest
```

But I am getting an error as :

```
useradd: group mytest exists - if you want to add this user to that group, use -g.
```

How can I fix this error, please help.

I have gone through this SO post - [Adding User and Group in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681057/adding-user-and-group-in-unix), but it is not helpful.

Comment: This is because Ubuntu tries to create a group with the same name as the user you are creating. As you see in the error message, you need to specify the group so that this behaviour is skipped: `useradd -g mytest mytest` etc.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot, the command `useradd -g mytest mytest` worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in comments:

This is because Ubuntu tries to create a group with the same name as the user you are creating. As you see in the error message, you need to specify the group so that this behaviour is skipped:

```
useradd -g mytest mytest
```